# How can 2 Character instead of 1 in My Textbox?

Tags: vb.net

My problem is very simple. this code works only on txtDraw (Letter) & Y.
Example: txtDrawA1, txtDrawA2, and so on. I want to make this code work as follows: txtDrawAA1, txtDrawAA2, replacing a character to be 2 characters.

This Code: `Dim tbName = "txtDraw" & Chr(64 + x) & y`

```
Private Sub txtDrawSum()
    On Error Resume Next
    For y = 1 To 8
        Dim sum = 0
        For x = 16 To 30
            Dim tbName = "txtDraw" & Chr(64 + x) & y
            sum += CInt(Tab3.TabPages(1).Controls(tbName).Text)
        Next
        TabControl2.TabPages(4).Controls("SumDrawA" & (0 + y)).Text = sum.ToString()
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a tip - `On Error Resume Next` should never be used in .net - have a google for v.net exception handling. Much better. `On Error Resume Next`, just ignores the error and tries to stumble on, pretty much.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the simple solution would just be to repeat `Chr(64 + x)` twice i.e.:

```
Dim tbName = "txtDraw" & Chr(64 + x) & Chr(64 + x) & y
```

but a better approach would be to use the `String` constructor:

```
Dim tbName = "txtDraw" &  New String(Chr(64 + x), 2) & y
```

or `Strings.StrDup`:

```
Dim tbName = "txtDraw" & StrDup(2, Chr(64 + x)) & y
```

This is better because say suddenly you want to repeat the character 10 times, you wouldn't have to duplicate the code as in the first example.

---

As an aside, you might want to use string interpolation to clean up the concatenations:

```
Dim tbName = $"txtDraw {StrDup(2, Chr(64 + x))} {y}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the replace function.

```
OldString.ToString().Replace("txtDrawA","txtDrawAA")
```